# Type of object after as cast?

Tags: c#, casting

Given that code:

```
class B
{
  public virtual string Method()
  {
     return "base";
  }
}

class D : B
{
  public override string Method()
  {
     return "derived";
  }
}

D d = new D();
B b = d as B;
b.Method();
```

"derived" is the output.

But why exactly?
I mean, b is a new object of type B, isnt it? Or is it the same object (in memory) as d? If so, what's the runtime type of b then, B or D?

Thanks

Comment: `b` has type `B` but points to the same object as `d` which has type `D`. The runtime type is also `D`.

Comment: Dont confuse with method *hiding*. i.e. `new` keyword. If you repalce *override* with *new*, it will actually prints `"base"`.

Comment: this is called runtime polymorphism

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule is simple: `b` is a reference to an object of type `D`. You could say that the run-time type of `b` is `D` but that's not particularly helpful terminology.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
B b = new D();
b.Method();
```

and you'd still get "derived". As @Bathsheba mentioned, what matters is the object type not the reference.

Imagine the typical OOP example where you have a base class `Shape` with derived classes `Circle`, `Square`, etc. with a virtual method `Area` .. if you have a method like this:

```
void ShowArea(Shape shape)
{
    Console.WriteLine(shape.Area());
}
```

The fact that the reference doesn't matter (but rather the actual object type) enables a method like the above to accept any type of `Shape` and still print the correct area

Answer (score 1):

> b is a new object of type B, isnt it?

No, `b` is an *existing* object of type `B`, which points to the same object you created just above it: `d`.  The only difference is that you have cast the object as its parent type -- `B`, so `b` is treated as a `B` rather than the more-derived type `D`.

The reason you get the output "derived" is because the method is overridden in the derived class and that's how overriding works.  Just because you declare a variable (i.e. `b`) as its less-derived type `B` doesn't mean it isn't still actually the more-derived type `D`.  That's the nature of polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

```
B b = d as B;
```

I believe this line of code only cast d to the type of  class B but the value still remain as 'derived'.